# Android studio problem with code formatting

Tags: android, android-studio

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvmb.png) i have got this problem after updating android studio 3.6.1 . Every file code turns to different format.
Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling android studio.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1.clear your project and rebuild it
2.restart android studio
3.Uninstall and reinstall [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)